# angular-ui-bootstrap 2.5.6 not working with AngularJS 1.7.8

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm attempting to convert a project I'm working on that used regular Javascript, jQuery, and Bootstrap into an AngularJS single page project and I'd like to keep using the Bootstrap library for it. I followed the instructions and downloaded the necessary files at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ but when I try loading my project at http://localhost:5000 I get none of my page loaded and an error in the console. I downloaded angular-ui-bootstrap in my project with the command "npm install angular-ui-bootstrap" from my Node.JS command prompt

In index.html I have tried changing the order of the script and link tags in my head section to no success. I have also tried removing the 'ui.bootstrap' dependency in main.module.js to see if AngularJS works by only loading my 'recipeList' dependency and it does work.

From main.module.js:

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'recipeList']);
```

From index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.module.js"></script>
        <script src="recipe-list\recipe-list.module.js"></script>
        <script src="recipe-list\recipe-list.component.js"></script>
        <title>Sousmate</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1>Sousmate</h1>
            </header>
            <section>
                <recipe-list></recipe-list>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.7.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.bootstrap%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.7.8%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dui.bootstrap%250AF%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A168%250AHe%252F%253C%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A453%250Ab%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A478%250AHe%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A227%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A496%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A76%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A344%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A43%253A27%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A76%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A344%250Afb%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A46%253A460%250Ac%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A22%253A57%250AUc%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A22%253A370%250AAe%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A45%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A348%253A494%250Ab%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A444%250A%0AF%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A168%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A285%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A76%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A344%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A27%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A76%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A344%0Afb%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A460%0Ac%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A57%0AUc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A370%0AAe%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A45%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A348%3A494%0Ab%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A444%0A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

> Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

From your html I don't see that you've included the angular bootstrap js.  You need this file along side your bootstrap css.  You can download it [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js).

e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Of course it was something as simple as that, thank you! However, my Bootstrap cards are not showing up at all. Was the card class deprecated in this version?

Comment: I'm not sure this version has any directives for cards, also your bootstrap version is 3 from what I can see, cards were introduced in bootstrap 4